# Assign the date for system.net email outlook appointment visual basic

Tags: system.net.mail

I am using the following code to send an outlook appointment using system.net.mail 
The code works perfectly and i am able to receive the appointment. But the problem is i can't figure out how to assign the appointment start date or end date

```
    'Str.AppendLine(String.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.Now))
     Str.AppendLine(String.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.UtcNow))
     Str.AppendLine(String.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.Now.AddHours(3)))
```

1) How do i set the UTC, as if i assign current date now it's always +8. can i just provide a date time without using UTC. 
2) And how do i specify the date time in the code. cause right now it use DateTime.Now then works. But manual assign not working

The complete code as below

```
Dim testMessage As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
    Dim fromAddress As New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("email@abc.com")
    Dim objSmtpClient As New SmtpClient(smtpIP, 25)
    Dim mailAttachment As Attachment
    Dim iserror As Boolean = False




    Try

        testMessage.From = fromAddress
        testMessage.To.Add("email2@abc.com")
        testMessage.Subject = "Training Scheduled"
        testMessage.Priority = MailPriority.Normal
        testMessage.Body = "Test"
        testMessage.IsBodyHtml = False


        Dim Str As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        Str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR")
        Str.AppendLine("PRODID:-//Schedule a Meeting")
        Str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0")
        Str.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST")
        Str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT")
        Str.AppendLine(String.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.Now))
        'Str.AppendLine(String.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.Now))
        Str.AppendLine(String.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.UtcNow))
        Str.AppendLine(String.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.Now.AddHours(3)))
        'Str.AppendLine(String.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.Now))
        'Str.AppendLine("LOCATION: " + Me.Location)
        Str.AppendLine(String.Format("UID:{0}", Guid.NewGuid()))
        Str.AppendLine(String.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", testMessage.Body))
        Str.AppendLine(String.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", testMessage.Body))
        Str.AppendLine(String.Format("SUMMARY:{0}", testMessage.Subject))
        Str.AppendLine(String.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", testMessage.From.Address))

        Str.AppendLine(String.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=""{0}"";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", testMessage.[To](0).DisplayName, testMessage.[To](0).Address))

        Str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM")
        Str.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT15M")
        Str.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY")
        Str.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:Reminder")
        Str.AppendLine("END:VALARM")
        Str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT")
        Str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR")

        Dim contype As New System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar")
        contype.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST")
        contype.Parameters.Add("name", "Meeting.ics")
        Dim avCal As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(Str.ToString(), contype)
        testMessage.AlternateViews.Add(avCal)





        objSmtpClient.Send(testMessage)
    Catch ex As Exception
        'MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        iserror = True
    Finally
        objSmtpClient = Nothing
        'alertMessage = Nothing
        fromAddress = Nothing
    End Try
```